# Prompt user from bash command substitution

Tags: bash, input

I am looking for a one-liner to prompt user for multiple inputs and execute a command using the user inputs as arguments.

The naive approach is:

```
read -p shirt_size: shirt_size
read -p age: age
the_command some_complicated_arguments $shirt_size $age
```

Unfortunately it is verbose.
Here is a one-liner that behaves the same:

```
the_command some_complicated_arguments \
  `>&2 printf shirt_size:; head -n 1` `>&2 printf age:; head -n 1`
```

Unfortunately it is neither compact nor readable.
I would like it to be as readable as:

```
the_command some_complicated_arguments \
  `input shirt_size` `input age`
```

I would prefer the solution to use bash built-in command or programs usually available on Linux environment.

Comment: I'd use the first approach, it's not excessively verbose and will be far more readable than anything shorter. Alternatively if you have lots of variables you can put them in a for loop.

Comment: I would like to prevent execution the command without the section that reads the input, which would result in either an error or a harmful behaviour.

Comment: Your one-liner is not equivalent to the original code, as it doesn't set any variables. Immediately printing and discarding the input doesn't seem like a valuable thing to do.

Comment: The original attempt is also superior because it doesn't require any subshells to be forked. Command substitution should only be used where necessary.

Comment: Why does no one seem to use `use --command line arguments any more`?

Comment: @chepner The point is to provide enhanced place holder that prompt the user. I'm more interested here the program behavior, as opposite to implementation details such as sub-process. Setting variable is more a drawback for my usecase.

Comment: @msw The point here is to document command lines with most of arguments hardcoded, and to prompt user for a few other arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a homework question to get you to look at functions.  If you had a function like:

```
input() { read -p "$1:" user_input; echo "$user_input"; }
```

Then your line:

```
the_command some_complicated_arguments "$(input shirt_size)" "$(input age)"
```

Would prompt and print the complete line.  Although this does nothing to check for valid input or no input.

Comment: You should fix the quoting, though. Put everything in double quotes.